# How do I get a centered button to stay in a div depending on screen size? (The image explains more)

Tags: html, css

[Here's a picture of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0P43.png)

I am using button code from UIverse and I have them aligned to the center.

My only issue here is that when I use another screen size the buttons come out of the div. The code I am using will be listed below in a codeblock. If anyone can help I would love this. I'm making a concept website for my school. The image above shows how 'Organizations' is out of the orange div. I need it aligned in center inside the div so it's flexible on screen sizes.

I would love some help, Thanks!

```
button {
    --hover-shadows: 16px 16px 33px #ffffff,
                      -16px -16px 33px #ffffff00;
    --accent: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    border-radius: 1.1em;
    background-color: #ff7300;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    transition: box-shadow ease-in-out 0.3s,
                background-color ease-in-out 0.1s,
                letter-spacing ease-in-out 0.1s,
                transform ease-in-out 0.1s;
                border: solid;
                border-width: 3px;
                border-color: #ffffff;
                display: block;
                 margin: 0 auto;
    
   }
   
   button:hover {
    box-shadow: var(--hover-shadows);
   }
   
   button:active {
    box-shadow: var(--hover-shadows),
                 var(--accent) 0px 0px 30px 5px;
    background-color: var(--accent);
    transform: scale(0.95);
   }

   #navbuttons {
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff7300;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
#Theactualbuttons {
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

I have tried changing the flex values and margin values, it didn't seem to work really well.

Comment: Please provide your html too.

Comment: Can you show the full screen view? Also how in the middle? You want all your buttons to stay in a line? or you want the ```div``` to grow taller to accommodate the flex change?

Comment: You can try to google how to center using `position: absolute;` way.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! What is the total height of a `button` and how high is `#navbuttons`? How high should `#navbuttons` be when a button wraps to the next line? Does it currently fit? (Assuming that `#navbuttons` is the main container holding the buttons, post a [reprex] so we can verify). The button container overflows simply because it is not tall enough: remove `#navbuttons { height: .. }` and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **flex-box** with justify set to centre or space-evenly

the following link describes their use nicely
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

rough example:

**CSS**

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #ff7300;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*might want to try nowrap*/
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav a {
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
  <a class="button">Home</a>
  <a class="button">Information</a>
  <a class="button">Curriculum</a>
  <a class="button">Staff Directory</a>
  <a class="button">Student Activities</a>
  <a class="button">Organizations</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I used the code listed below to fix it. Thanks for the help.

Edit: I pasted the wrong thing. This is the actual code I used. I also upped the div sizes a bit. Thanks for all the help!

```
display: inline-block;
display: -moz-inline-box;
*display: inline; /* For IE7 */
zoom: 1; /* Trigger hasLayout */
text-align: center;
margin-left: 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height for the div container (can bee %) and button position to relative.